# Reverse stack without using any data structure

Tags: algorithm, stack

How can I Reverse stack without using any (extra) data structure ? Any suggestions or Pseudo code could be helpful . I trying and couldn't find any viable solution . Problem here is I don-no the size of stack also . If i know that I could at-least proceed on creating something , Thanks in advance .

Comment: Since the stack itself is a data structure, are you allowed to use that?

Comment: What can you do is pop all element of the current stack and push them to another. I'm not if that would suit you though.

Comment: How's the stack implemented? If it's your own implementation with a linked list, just reverse direction of pointers.

Comment: @chill, better yet - use a double ended queue

Comment: @Leeor nice one. Recursion does use a stack which is inbuilt. Is this a stupid interview question (Sometimes they ask such, why would anyone do with recursion,it is so expensive)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done with double recursion , as [follows:](http://www.careercup.com/question?id=12689669) .

```cpp
void insert_at_bottom(node **stack, int data)
{
     if( isempty(*stack) ){
          push(stack,data);
          return;
     }
     int temp=pop(stack);
     insert_at_bottom(stack,data);
     push(stack,temp);
}  


void rev_stack(node **stack)
{
     if( isempty(*stack) ) return;
     int temp = pop(stack);
     rev_stack(stack);
     insert_at_bottom(stack,temp);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can easily do this using recursion. Then your maximum allowed stack size would be bound by maximum recursion depth. Some code:

```cpp
public void reverse(Stack st) { 
    int m = (int)st.Pop(); 
    if (st.Count != 1) {
        reverse(st); 
    }
    Push(st , m); 
  } 

public void Push(Stack st , int a) { 
   int m = (int)st.Pop(); 
   if (st.Count != 0) {
       Push(st , a); 
   }
   else {
       st.Push(a); 
       st.Push(m); 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different approach. I"m trying to use fixed set of variables (5 - max,A,A1,B,B1) and re-utilizing these variables, re-populating stack in reverse order.

No-Recursion.

Only works for Integers

Let's say Stack = [1,2,-3,4] with 1 on top.

max = 5

A = ((((((1*5)+2)*5)+3)*5)+4)*5

A1 = (((((((0+5)*5)+5)*5)+6)*5)+5)*5

With the help of A and A1 you can re-populate the stack but in the same order so calculating B and B1 which are in reverse order.

A1 & B1 are to remember negative integers.

Here, + max is for positive and + (max + 1) to remember negative integers.

```
import java.util.Stack;
//Not ideal solution. This is only because no other data structure can be used

/*
 * 1. Find Max. Any number > max can be used for max
 * 2. Find A and A1
 * 3. Find B and B1
 * 4. Fill the Stack using B and B'
 * O( 4n ) = O( n )
 */

class Stack_Reversal_Using_Recursion { 

static Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>(); 

public static void main(String[] args) {

    stack.push(1);
    stack.push(8);
    stack.push(-3);
    stack.push(0);
    stack.push(4);
    System.out.println(stack);  

    better_Solution();

    System.out.println("Using mathematical approch");
    System.out.println(stack);

}
private static void better_Solution() {

    int size = stack.size();

    //Finding Max
    int max = 0;
    for(int item : stack){
        if( max < Math.abs(item) )
            max = Math.abs(item);
    }
    max = max + 1;

    //Finding A and A1
    int A = 0;
    int A1 = 0;

    while( stack.size() > 0 )
    {
        int x = stack.pop();
        A += Math.abs(x);
        A *= max;

        if( x < 0 )
            A1 += (max+1);
        else
            A1 += max;
        A1 *= max;
    }
    //A and A' hold single sum total value from which using max we can find out entire stack but in same order so we find out B and B1

    int B = 0;
    int B1 = 0;

    for( int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        A = A / max;
        A1 = A1/ max;

        int A_mdl = A % max;
        A -= A_mdl;

        int A1_mdl = A1 % max;
        if( A1_mdl == 0 )
            A1_mdl = max;
        else
            A1_mdl = max + 1;
        A1 -= A1_mdl;

        B += A_mdl;
        B *= max;

        B1 += A1_mdl;
        B1 *= max;

    }

    //Now that we have B and B1 in desired order let's re-populate the Stack
    for( int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        B = B / max;
        B1 = B1/ max;

        int B_mdl = B % max;
        B -= B_mdl;

        int B1_mdl = B1 % max;
        if( B1_mdl != 0 )
            B_mdl = -B_mdl;
        if( B1_mdl ==0 )
            B1 -= max;
        else
            B1 -= (max+1);

        stack.push( B_mdl );

    }

}

}
```

As stated earlier, This approach is only for Integers and one can always debate what if numbers are vary large! In that case As and Bs can be Big Integers.